# What would be the best way to sum all the credit values from this JSON output?

Tags: flutter

refer to the link below for the image, I want to know how can we add all the credit values what would be the best way to implement this.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/raA5x.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the Ledger list using a for statement. Take a look at the example below:

```dart
final data = {
  "Ledger": [
    {"Credit Amount": 1000},
    {"Credit Amount": 1000},
    {"Credit Amount": 1000},
    {"Credit Amount": 1000},
    {"Credit Amount": 1000},
  ],
};

var sum = 0;
for (final item in data['Ledger']) {
  sum += item['Credit Amount'];
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful. I am using a different method to implement this. I am using fold to use this.                    num credit = stmt.fold(0, (a, b) => a + b["Credit Amount"]);

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, you can do it like that too. If it was useful please accept and vote up ;)